# GAE datastore date property auto produce date of 1970

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have datastore Model bellow:

```
class ThisCategory(search.SearchableModel):
    ancestor = db.ListProperty(db.Key, default=[])
    no_ancestor = db.BooleanProperty(default=True)
    name = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty()
    last_modified = db.TimeProperty(auto_now=True) #<----- (1970-01-01 15:36:47.987352) in datastore
```

How to create/result correct now date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `TimeProperty` is just a `DateTime` object with the date part set to 0 (which means 1970-01-01).

The idea is that when you use a `TimeProperty` you ignore the date part.

If you want to use the Date information too, then you want a `DateTimeProperty`.  The `DateTimeProperty`'s auto_now will properly set both the date and time parts.